# Merge PDF Files using the staplr Package in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge many pdf into one. I was trying the staplr package and I also install the pdftk in my system. But when I run for example: 
get_fields() it said that there wasn´t any file in the directory. Or staple_pdf() it run but doesn´t create the merge pdf.

Is there here someone who already worked with this package and can help me with?

Comment: Hi Matheus, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You should add the code you've tried to your question for other members to be able to help you. Thanks